# Remove underline on UITextView link

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'm trying the following to format links on UITextView:

```
self.textView.linkTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleNone]};
```

The issue is that, the link color was changed to white, but it's still underlined.

How can I solve it?

This is my `attributedString`:

```
{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.294118 0.254902 0.211765 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fd75a196010> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 24.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 24, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
}url.com{
    CTForegroundColorFromContext = 1;
    DTGUID = "44B87A68-642A-41AA-8CBA-48531DB58C57";
    DTLinkHighlightColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1";
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0.933333 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fd75a196010> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 24.00pt";
    NSLink = "http://www.url.com";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 24, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSUnderline = 1;
}
{
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fd75a196010> font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 24.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 24, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
}
```

Comment: Can you try this. Don't specified about Type of Data types.textview.linkTextAttributes = @{
                                NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor],
                                 NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)};

Comment: Can you remove data detector type?

Comment: Does not work. And no, I did not remove data detector, in fact, I enable it on my code (i updated my question).

Comment: Disable data detector then try it.

Comment: Same result, did not work with `UIDataDetectorTypeNone`.

Comment: @can you paste your string here?

Comment: Which attribute you will print for example? can you wish to print NSLink = "http://www.url.com"; in text view?

Comment: I will receive all of them. The text view will contain several news paragraph, and there will or will not appear urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an unknow reason, if I add the `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName` in `linkTextAttributes` didn't work. It supposed to add `NSUnderline = 0` to link, instead it add `NSUnderline = 1`. So, the only solution I found is to locate that attribute and replace it when found.

```
self.textView.linkTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]};

NSMutableAttributedString *res = [self.textView.attributedText mutableCopy];
[res beginEditing];
[res enumerateAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                inRange:NSMakeRange(0, res.length)
                options:0
             usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
                 if (value) {
                     [res addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:@(NSUnderlineStyleNone) range:range];
                 }
             }];
[res endEditing];

[self.textView setAttributedText:res];
```

Comment: While this works, setting underlineColor results in cleaner code. See Nevin's answer.

Answer (score 15):

For Swift, it's simply:

```
textView.linkTextAttributes = [.underlineStyle: 0]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work from `linkTextAttributes` but works using `attributedString.addAttribute(.underlineStyle, value: 0, range: range)`

Answer (score 13):

Somehow ".underlineStyle: 0" didn't work for me. so i had to clear the Underline Color and it worked for me.

```
textView.linkTextAttributes = [.underlineStyle: 0, .underlineColor: UIColor.clear,]
```

Comment: As far as I get it from docs, the zero-index underlineStyle is "single line"

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the `NSUnderlineStyle` in your UITextView's `linkTextAttributes` gets overridden by CSS's link style. If you do not define a `text-decoration` style for your HTML the `UITextView` sets the underline style to `styleSingle` because that is the default HTML style for a link.

To remove the underline you have to add a underline style for your HTML links. You could do that by adding the following CSS to the `head` of the HTML:

```
<style type='text/css'>
   a { text-decoration: none }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just set underline colour as clear colour.

```
yourTextView.linkTextAttributes = @{NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor]};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. I tried this & It's work for me. Please review them. May be it's helpful for you.

```
emailTV = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
emailTV.text = @"https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=eUMJVZrQIsTV8gflkoHwAQ&gws_rd=ssl";
emailTV.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
emailTV.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium"size:14.0+fontSizeDiff];
emailTV.selectable = NO;
emailTV.scrollEnabled = NO;
emailTV.editable = NO;
emailTV.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
emailTV.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
emailTV.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[cellVI addSubview: emailTV];
```

Comment: I need to remove it from an attributed text like the one in my question.