# How to disable underlining urls in NSMutableAttributedString for a label

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a label with attributed text. The text has url link which gets underlined with default blue color. How to remove the url underline style for `NSMutableAttributedString`?

```
func htmlToAttributedString(_ html: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
    guard let data = NSString(string: html).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) else { return nil }
    do {
        let attrStr = try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                      options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                      documentAttributes: nil)
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length)
        let str = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attrStr)
        str.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)], range: range)
        str.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: 0, range: range)
        return NSAttributedString(attributedString: str.attributedSubstring(from: range))
    } catch {}
    return nil
}
```

I tried with the above code, but it still show the decorated link.

[image: attributed-string-url]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117560/remove-underline-on-uitextview-link

Comment: try: str.removeAttribute(.underlineStyle, range: range)

Comment: `removeAttribute` is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate` through the attributes in the `attributedString`, and remove those for links…

```
attributedString.enumerateAttributes(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length), options: []) { attributes, range, stop in                
    attributedString.removeAttribute(.link, range: range)
    attributedString.removeAttribute(.foregroundColor, range: range)
    attributedString.removeAttribute(.underlineStyle, range: range)

}
```